# Is this possible with Git?

Tags: git-push, git-checkout, git-commit, git

I want my git repo to be at the state it was at a specific commit. Once the repo is at the state, I want to be able to push to Github, making the remote be at that state. I know I can call `git checkout <commit hash>` and my local repo will be at the state it was at the given commit, but it won't let you push.

I'm guessing that I should do something with `git checkout` but I don't know what to do.

Thanks for any help on this simple question :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to push with force since you are going to lose history.

```
git push -f origin master
```

This will forcefully push your changes. If you are trying to undo something, you may want to consider `git revert` since it will allow you to keep history.

Comment: OK thanks. I decided against `git revert`because it's a large difference in time between the current commit and the commit I want.

Comment: Why? Reverts are revertible. Losing history isn't.

Comment: I think that `git revert` is the correct way to go, but the OP will have to revert every individual commit between HEAD and the target commit, right? Unless there is another way to do this directly with a single git command.

Comment: @Jeet, `git revert` can take a range of commits.

Comment: @Karl: But merges are tough to revert.

Comment: Good point @Jefromi.  If you have merges in between, you can get the same effect with a `git reset --hard [commit]` followed immediately by `git reset HEAD@{1}`.  That changes your working directory back to where it was, but puts the branch head back in the same place, so everything looks like uncommitted changes.  Then just add, commit, and push as normal.

Answer (score 2):

Use `git reset --hard <commit>` to reset the repo to a particular commit.

This will make you lose your working directory changes and any commit after the `commit`. You can still get back the newer commits from `git reflog` and then using `git reset` on those commits.

Also, if you had already pushed the other commits, you must avoid pushing to the remote without them.